# Is it possible to get a NSArray from AppDelegate?

Tags: objective-c, appdelegate

Is it possible to get a NSArray from my AppDelegate? I need to send a array to other classes. And that array is generated in my AppDelegate. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, it's possible.  Do you know what a property is?  Have you used `[UIApplicaton sharedApplication].delegate`?

Comment: Yes. ITs is  possible

Comment: Nope didn't used it yet

Comment: How then? @HariKrishnan.P

Comment: can you check my answer

Comment: check my answer @drbj explained step by step and accept my answer

Comment: What you are doing is very wrong. Application delegate is not there for you to keep global variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you should have to `alloc` and `init`
In AppDelegate.h file

```
@property(nonatomic,retain)NSArray *books;
```

In AppDelegate.m file your array, then You can add objects in it.

```
_books = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"test",@"test", nil];
```

You should have to create AppDelegate instance in your `BooksDetailViewController` like this,

in .h file

```
AppDelegate *appDelegate;
```

and in .m file

```
appDelegate  = (AppDelegate*)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
```

Now you can access your array like this,

```
NSLog(@"Test Log :%@",appDelegate.books);
```

Output :

```
2016-07-14 13:04:08.211 Gridz[2490:39240] Test Log :(
test,
test
)
```

Comment: Lets say I have a NSArray *books in my AppDelegate. Why I can't access it in appDelegate.books? I am missing something, like setting the books in public or what?

Comment: have you set the property in appdelegate file

Answer (score 0):

```
AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
```

Now you can use any property or method like:

`[appDelegate myProperty]` or `[appDelegate myMethod]`

Hope this helps

Comment: Lets say I have a NSArray *books in my AppDelegate. Why I can't access it in [appDelegate books] I am missing something, like setting the books in public or what?

Comment: Make sure your array should be declared as property in AppDelegate.h file to get access outside the class.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to get the NSArray from AppDelegate to other classes.

AppDelegate.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate> {

}
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIWindow *window;
@property (nonatomic, strong) ViewController *viewController; //For Xib
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *arrayObjects;
@end
```

AppDelegate.m

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import "ViewController.h"
@implementation AppDelegate
@synthesize arrayObjects;
```

As I use Xib, I set the root view controller in below method.If you use stroy board, it is enough to add NSArray objects only.Don't need to set the root view controller.

```
//For XIB
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
   arrayObjects = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"Steve",@"jobs",@"Tim",@"Cook",nil];
   self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
   // Override point for customization after application launch.
   self.viewController = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil];
   UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:self.viewController];
   self.window.rootViewController = navController;
   [navController setNavigationBarHidden:YES];
   [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
   return YES;
}
//For Storyboard
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
   arrayObjects = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"Steve",@"jobs",@"Tim",@"Cook",nil];
   return YES;
}
```

Then in ViewController.m

You can also import the AppDelegate in ViewController.m

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "AppDelegate.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController
```

Now in viewDidLoad method

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
   [super viewDidLoad];
   // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    AppDelegate *delegate = (AppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    NSLog(@"The app delegate NSArray Objects are - %@",delegate.arrayObjects);
}
```

The NSLog results are

```
The app delegate NSArray Objects are - (
Steve,
jobs,
Tim,
Cook
)
```